# How to allow PPTP VPN access through APF firewall

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, iptables

I'm attempting to connect to a PPTP VPN. I have opened ports 47 and 1723 in the ingress rules. When APF is turned on, it fails. When APF is turned off, it works fine. I have turned on as many logging options as I can find, but there is no record of any packets being dropped, other than spam from other machines on the subnet. When APF is turned off, it works fine. I have turned on as many logging options as I can find, but there is no record of any packets being dropped, other than spam from other machines on the subnet. I found a site that said I should add a postrouting rule involving NAT, but that had no effect either.

SOLUTION: Add the following line to /etc/apf-firewall/postroute.rules -

`$IPT -A INPUT -p 47 -j ACCEPT`

Then, run this as root:

`service apf-firewall restart`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PPTP uses the GRE protocol. You must allow outbound connections for protocol 47 (that is GRE), not port 47.

Comment: Thanks! :) I had to decipher a bit of Portuguese to find the right way to add it to APF, but it worked immediately.